# Get dimension of HTML tag

Tags: php, html

I'm using [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) parse HTML file and I need the height and width of a given tag, in jQuery it's possible to use something like

```
height=$("div.content").height();
width=$("div.content").width();
```

but in PHPQuery there is no such thing as height(), width() functions so is there any way to get the dimensions?

Comment: That depends on CSS, images, and the HTML box model.  It also depends on the size of the area you're rendering in.  It can even depend on the page's own Javascript code. It's a very complicated question.

Comment: Isn't PHPQuery just a CSS selector DOM API? I.e. has nothing to do with the ouput at any point? May I remind you that PHP (even PHPQuery) is *serverside*.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery on the server-side, you can do everytime with a headless browser. http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: ok i get it but i'm wondering if i can append javascript code to the HTML page and get the dimensions using jquery and sent it using ajax to php file , is that possible?

Comment: @Farok Ojil: Sure, that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPQuery just lets you traverse the document in a manner similar to jQuery.  It does not actually render the document and so it has no idea what size each element will actually be when rendered by a browser.

In order to compute the width and height of an element, it would need to parse your stylesheet, apply all of those rules, fetch any images used by that element (and its descendants) and render the element using the appropriate font(s) -- and possibly even render parent elements as well.  And there's no guarantee that the resulting dimensions will match some particular client configuration, since the client-side environment may cause the element to render at a different size (DPI being the most obvious example, but even the size of the browser window could affect the size of any given element).